# Jenkins running on headless linux aws with xvfb getting error for the connectedAndroidTest espresso

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-espresso

Giving Error on jenkins while running android espresso test.
My server is headless linux aws, and i am using xvfb to run android emulator virtually and want to run test cases.
i have already create emulator with command line

```
android create avd --force -n nexus4-emulator2 -t "Google Inc.:Google APIs:18" --abi default/armeabi-v7a -s "768x1280" --device "Nexus 4" -c 128M
```

this is creating emulator, first it was giving permission error, but after adding access permission it get resolved.

now some of logs on jenkins is like below

> [android] Starting Android emulator
>
> $ /opt/android-sdk-linux//platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5788
>   wait-for-device shell getprop init.svc.bootanim [android] Emulator
>   reported that the startup process is 'running'
>
> [android] Attempting to unlock emulator screen
>
> :Chynge:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>
> Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'nexus4-emulator(AVD) - 4.3.1' for
>   Chynge:debug Installed on 1 device.
>
> :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest
>
> com.app_positive.LoginTest > loginTest[nexus4-emulator(AVD) - 4.3.1]
>   [31mFAILED [0m    android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException:
>   No views in hierarchy found matching: (with id: com.app:id/btn_login
>   and with text: is "Login with E-Mail" and is displayed on the screen
>   to the user)
>
> :app:connectedDebugAndroidTest FAILED
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
>
>   > There were failing tests. See the report at: file:///data/jenkins/workspace/android-ci-tests/client/android/app/build/reports/androidTests/connected/index.html
>
> [Gradle] - Launching build.
>
> Build step 'Invoke Gradle script' changed build result to FAILURE Xvfb
>   stopping Finished: FAILURE

Comment: problem: `NoMatchingViewException`: it says that Espresso didn't find a view with `btn_login` id and `Login with E-Mail` text. Did you run tests from Android Studio or locally from Gradle console ?

Comment: of course i run it locally with Android Studio and with command line too..View is there on the screen, so why not getting it? i have a doubt if this is because of emulator configuration(a screens size) or any permission(update for google play) may popping on screen..or emulator haven't get unlock totally and test cases starts running..Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

[![Emulator Configuration][see here]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOYcF.png)[![Gradle task configuration][see here]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reRGF.png) I haven't added command to create emulator or to open it, but Jenkins provides android emulator plugin that do all things like creating emulator, wait to open, launch emulator, i just have to add configuration for it.
finally i got answer, i tried to create emulator on my windows machine with same configuration on Jenkins,and install app on it , it was showing google play service update pop up, and that's the reason, runner unable to find view on screen, as pop up don't allow to run the app, query of creating emulator is like

path upto android_sdk_tools>> android create avd --force -n emualator_29 -t android-23 --abi google_apis/armeabi-v7a -s "768x1280" --device "Nexus 4" -c 128M

just by taking new version 23, some ideal screen resolution, and one more only armeabi-v7a runs on headless machine...it works for me..thank you..

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used ever `Jenkins`, but I used `Travis CI` for building my Github projects. I know that can after installing plugin read `Travis` configuration files with `.yml` extensions.

Here's my configuration of Android emulator

```
 - echo no | android create avd --force -n test -t $ANDROID_TARGET --abi armeabi-v7a --sdcard 200M
  - emulator -avd test -no-audio -no-window &
  - android-wait-for-emulator
  - sleep 10
  - adb shell settings put global window_animation_scale 0 &
  - adb shell settings put global transition_animation_scale 0 &
  - adb shell settings put global animator_duration_scale 0 &
  - adb shell input keyevent 82 &
```

> From: https://github.com/piotrek1543/LocalWeather/blob/master/.travis.yml

As you can see after creating an emulator instance (first line), I'm executing `android-wait-for-emulator` as loading the virtual device may take more than few minutes and `Espresso` test may start before emulator woulb in idle. Also remember to turn off animation and unlock the screen (tha last line).

Try to write similar script.

**EDIT:** As you're using headless server **uncheck** this options:

- show emulator window

> ### Running on headless build machines
>
> If you have build slaves which are
>   headless (e.g. Linux servers that don't have a graphical user
>   interface), you can still run an Android Emulator even although, by
>   default, the emulator does require a graphical environment.
>
> Just untick the "Show emulator window" configuration option in your
>   job configuration. This is the equivalent of using the emulator's
>   "-no-window" command-line option.
>
> From: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin

- use emulator snapshots

> Similarly, snapshot support does not fully function for Android 4.0
>   until SDK Tools r15. An initial snapshot can be created, but
>   subsequently loading from that snapshot will crash the emulator
>   immediately. Earlier Android versions are not affected, i.e. you can
>   still use snapshots with Android 3.2 and earlier. Upgrading to SDK
>   Tools r15+ should fix this.
>
> As a workaround, you can also uncheck "Use emulator snapshots" in any
>   jobs where you are seeing problems.
>
> From: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin

The same solution is described on that screen:

> [image]
>
> From http://blog.zuehlke.com/en/configure-your-android-project-on-jenkins/

**EDIT2**: Read this article: https://www.cloudbees.com/blog/continuous-integration-mobile-apps-jenkins-android-builds and notice:

[image]

Notice that you can add some additional scripts to your emulator, try to use mine without first line.

Hope it will help